# Returning multiple variables from a single list

Tags: python, list

Using Python 3

This is very basic I'm sure. The code is used to return the Country, from the country code provided. Essentially I need the first two letters of the input given.

The code I've worked so far will only output the first "country code"

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    c = prices.split(',')
    for char in c:
        return char[:2]


print(get_country_codes("NZ$300, KR$1200, DK$5"))

output:
   NZ
Wanted output:
   NZ, KR, DK
```

Comment: Your `return` is executed in the first iteration of the `for` loop. So that is why you never see the other outputs you desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    values = []
    price_codes = prices.split(',')
    for price_code in price_codes: 
        values.append(price_code.strip()[0:2])

    return values # output: ['NZ', 'KR', 'DK']

    return ', '.join(values) # output: NZ, KR, DK

print(get_country_codes("NZ$300, KR$1200, DK$5"))
```

output:

```
['NZ', 'KR', 'DK']
```

basically your method was returning the first value from that `split` list.

You need to iterate on that split list and save each value in another list and return that.

Another approach:

```
country_price_values = "NZ$300, KR$1200, DK$5"

country_codes = [val.strip()[0:2] for val in country_price_values.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to one liner this:

```
>>> def get_country_codes(prices):
    return [cc.strip()[:2] for cc in prices.split(',')]

>>> print(get_country_codes("NZ$300, KR$1200, DK$5"))
['NZ', 'KR', 'DK']
>>>
```

What your program was doing was executing the `for` loop, but when `return` is called, it terminates the function; your implementation looked as though you wanted a generator (i.e. using `yield`) which is doable, but probably more cumbersome than necessary for this.